# When does $\sigma(X_1,..,X_n)=\sigma(f(X_1,...,X_n))$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Given $n$ random variables $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}:(\Omega,\mathcal{F}) \to (\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$. We can consider $\sigma(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})$ which is the smallest sigma algebra on $\Omega$ to make $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ measurable. I think consider $g:\Omega \to (\mathbb{R}^{k},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$, $g(\omega)=(X_{1}(\omega ),\dots,X_{n}(\omega))$, this is the smallest sigma algebra to make $g$ measurable, or in other word, $\sigma(g) = \sigma(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})$. Is this correct?

> If so, I think given any measurable map $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to (C, \mathscr{C})$, where $f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}) = f \circ g$, so $\sigma(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})) \subset \sigma(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})$ as $f$ is composition of two measurable map, thus measurable.

> But when does $\sigma(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})) = \sigma(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})$? For instance, if $C$ is the reals the natural number, or some common sets, when is this true? Does strict monotonicity of $f$ suffice if $C =\mathbb{R}$, or something else? What about some functions like $\prod_{i}e^{\alpha_{i}X_{i}}$ (for some $(\alpha_{i})$).

I don't know if the converse is true very often or if there is some nontrivial conclusion to make.

My motivation is somewhat related to conditional expectation, where we condition on different sigma fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looking at the collection $X_1,...,X_n$ we can look at the vector $Y = (X_1,...,X_n)$ for which $\sigma(Y) = \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$, so it is enough to consider case of single random variable $Y$ (but taking values in some product space $\mathbb R^n$ or any different).

Thus, let us assume that $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ is some probability space, $(S,\mathcal S)$ is some measurable space and $Y:\Omega \to S$ is $\mathcal F/\mathcal S$ measurable random variable $($ in your case $S=\mathbb R^d$, $\mathcal S = \mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$. As you noticed, for any measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$ and $\mathcal S/\mathcal E$ measurable map $f:S \to E$ it is true that $\sigma(f(Y)) \subset \sigma(Y)$. Indeed, any $A \in \sigma(f(Y))$ is of the form $(f(Y))^{-1}[B] = Y^{-1}[f^{-1}[B]]$ for some $B \in \mathcal E$, but since $f$ is $\mathcal S/\mathcal E$ measurable, ten $f^{-1}[B] \in \mathcal S$ and hence $A = Y^{-1}[ f^{-1}[B]] \in \sigma(Y)$.

To talk about other inclusion $\sigma(Y) \subset \sigma(f(Y))$ (so the case of equality), we shall need some technical assumptions.

Firstly, recall the (Doob-Dynkin) factorisation lemma

$\textbf{Lemma.}$ Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$, $(E,\mathcal E)$ be measurable spaces. Consider $\mathcal F / \mathcal E$ measurable mapping $X:\Omega \to E$ and $\mathcal F /\mathcal B([0,1])$ measurable mapping $Y: \Omega \to [0,1]$. Then, $\sigma(Y) \subset \sigma(X)$ if and only if, $Y = g(X)$ for some $\mathcal E/\mathcal B([0,1])$ measurable mapping $g:E \to [0,1]$.

This extends almost immediately from the case of $([0,1],\mathcal B([0,1]))$ to the case of the space $(S,\mathcal S)$ borel-isomorphic to $([0,1],\mathcal B([0,1]))$. In particular, by the (non-trivial) result of Alexandrov, we can take $S$ to be a Polish space here and for the sake of convenience we shall only consider Polish space $S$ below with its Borel $\sigma-$field $\mathcal B(S)$.

The above lemma allows us to say that if $(\Omega,\mathcal F), (E,\mathcal E)$ are measurable and $(S,\mathcal B(S))$ is Polish, $Y:\Omega \to S$ is $\mathcal F/\mathcal B(S)$ measurable and $f:S \to E$ is $\mathcal S/\mathcal E$ measurable, then $\sigma(Y) \subset \sigma(f(Y))$ iff there exists $\mathcal E/\mathcal B(S)$ measurable mapping $g:E \to S$ such that $Y = g(f(Y))$. In other words there exists a left inverse of $f$. In particular, $f$ must be injective on range of $Y$ and $g=f^{-1}$ on the image of $f$.

This motivates very well your question; any strictly monotone $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has left inverse and then (with a little abuse of notation treating $f$ as a map $f:\mathbb R \to f[\mathbb R]$) we would have $Y = f^{-1}(f(Y))$ and so the positive answer to your question should follow from above consideration, right? Well, yes, but there is a little subtetly that we need to ensure (Borel) measurability of $f^{-1}$. In the case of strictly monotone $\textbf{continuous}$ function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ it is quite obvious due to images of open intervals being open intervals, but in the general case we need the following(non-trivial) result due to Kuratowski / Lusin - Suslin (in fact, the particular case of it)

$\textbf{Theorem.}$ Assume that $f:S \to E$ is a Borel mapping between Polish spaces $(S,\mathcal B(S)), (E,\mathcal B(E))$. If $f$ is injective, then images of Borel sets under $f$ remains Borel. In particular, if $f$ is bijective, then $f^{-1}:E \to S$ is again Borel measurable.

Hence, if in our setting both $S$ and $E$ are Polish spaces equipped with Borel $\sigma-$fields, then for any surjective random variable $Y:\Omega \to S$ and Borel function $f:S \to E$ we have $\sigma(Y) = \sigma(f(Y))$ if and only if $f$ is injective. The neccesity is due to the factorisation lemma (there must exists a left inverse of $f$) and the sufficiency follows from above Theorem. Indeed, if $f:S \to E$ is injective, then $f[S]$ is a Borel subset of Polish space $E$, so it is well known that $f[S]$ is again a Polish space. In particular, $f:S \to f[S]$ is Borel bijective between Polish spaces and so has Borel inverse $f^{-1}$. We then have $Y = f^{-1}( f(Y))$ and so $\sigma(Y) = \sigma( f^{-1}(f(Y))) \subset \sigma(f(Y))$.

$\textbf{Remark 1.}$ It works well with random variable $Y=(X_1,...,X_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ and function $f(x_1,...,x_n) = (e^{a_1 x_1},...,e^{a_n x_n})$ (for non-zero constants $a_i$) since $x\mapsto e^{ax}$ is invertible as a function $\mathbb R \to (0,\infty)$. But if you have $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ with $m < n$ then usually you "lose" some information and hence $\sigma(f(X_1,...,X_n)) = \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$ rarely holds.

$\textbf{Remark 2.}$ It indeed seems to be quite useful in the considerations involving conditional expectation/probability. I encountered it mostly during studying Markov Processes (considering functions of Markov processes it is quite convenient to know whether the conditioning on $f(X_t)$ and $X_t$ is the same or not).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! This is a nice result to use.

Comment: Wait, for Remark 1, I don't think f is injective?

Comment: Of course it isn't, I meant something else, edited.